# Regex for currency

Tags: jquery, regex

I am trying to create a currency regex in jquery. Everything works fine except it includes numbers with a minus sign in the middle like "1-3"

I am using a match function with the following regex:

```
/[\$€£]\d{0,3},?\d{1,3}(.\d{2})?/g
```

Does anyone have any idea why the minus sign is being included?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The minus sign is being included because you have a `.` in the middle of your regex. `.` indicates that it can match any character.

Comment: Darn, three seconds faster than me XD Have a +1

Answer (score 5):

Escape the `.`, otherwise it matches any character. In this case, it matches `-`.

Also note that you don't need to escape the `$` since it has no meaning inside a character class `[...]`

EDIT: Here's what I'd use:

```
/^[$£€]\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{2})?$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the autoNumeric plugin of jquery plugin that automatically formats currency and numbers as you type on form inputs
First - include jQuery.js and autoNumeric-1.9.19.js javascript files in the header.

Second - insert a form and input field on the HTML/JSP document.

Third - in a separate script initialize autoNumeric $('selector').autoNumeric('init').

jQuery(function($) {

```
  $('#someID_defaults').autoNumeric('init', {aSign:',', pSign:'£', vMax:'99999.99' });
```

});